# Why are people using Django templates with webpack to connect DRF with ReactJS?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Am I missing something?

But I am really not getting the rationale behind most online blogs and tutorials suggesting to use a base Django template to render a ReactJS bundle (bundled from webpack).

In my mind, the point of using Django Rest Framework in the first place is to **completely** isolate the frontend from the backend and have something like Nginx serving an html file that would import the ReactJS library (like any other stndard html/js project). The ReactJS layer would then get or manipulate data solely through the DRF REST API.

It is like most developers treat ReactJS as a completely novel beast, when it can be simply treated as standard JS (with added steroids) that runs on the browser.

Can someone therefore explain to me what are the advantages of using the methods depicted by blogs such as [Jonathan Cox](http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework) and [Owaislone](http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On one part, you're right. One of React's principles is to make it function like a Mobile app(that consumes REST API) which also compliments React-Native, so there's not much for the programmer to learn and pick up and can quickly develop an app if they are familiar with React. This way, you'd build the back-end to serve both the web app and the native mobile app without much rewriting or customizing.

Usually, people like keeping their code together, front-end and the back-end if they're just developing for the web. It's a common practice. Since Django is widely used and is also an open source framework amongst a lot of web-developers, there's a big community to develop tools or plugins for it. This way, they'd just have one server instance running and configure the backend to serve just the index.html page, and the routing is handled by the browser.

I, on the other hand, prefer the latter part, work on a team with backend engineers and mobile developers. We heavily rely on RESTful calls for our apps. So we keep our code base neat and isolate our backend from our front-end so each of us can work independently.

It's just a matter of preference really, Jonathan Cox and Owaislone both don't preach about the right way to develop React apps, they just demonstrated one of the ways React can be used.

Also, some backends have a lot of security and need to be configured to allow certain headers for making requests. It could make you look at your computer screen for days while you sit there wondering how to work around the problem and you're diving deep into the documentation for web requests. CORS is one of the problems when you isolate your front end and back end code. It's something that can totally be avoided if Django is serving the files.

I'd say you can go ahead and pick one that suits your need, isolate your React code from the backend if you'd want the back end to work on mobile apps too, saves a lot of time.